# Как скопировать данные одного массива в другой js?

Tags: javascript, массивы, copy

Итак, есть у меня функция

```
function SaveMyDeck(arr1, arr2) {
  var arr3 = [];
  arr2 = arr3.concat(arr1);
  console.log('Save Deck:'+arr2 );
};
```

Которая по идее должна сохранять содержимое массива arr2 в массив arr1. Но она не работает и я не понимаю почему. Консоль тоже ни на что не ругается.

Так же пробовал варианты вроде:

```
 1. for (var i=0; i<arr1.lenght - 1; i++) {arr2[i] = arr1[i]};
 2. arr2.push(arr1);
 3. arr2 = [].concat(arr1);
```

И еще несколько подобных комбинаций, но ни одна не сработала как надо. Что я делаю не так? Как заставить данные одного массива переместиться в другой?

Содержимое массива arr1 (так он отображается в консоли в процессе чтения):

```
0: Cards
accuracy: 30
attak: 10
attaktipe: "melee"
defence: 5
dexterity: 50
health: 100
speed: 10
suits: "spearman"
[[Prototype]]: Object
1: Cards
accuracy: 80
attak: 15
attaktipe: "melee"
defence: 10
dexterity: 30
health: 100
speed: 5
suits: "armoredman"
[[Prototype]]: Object
```

Второй массив просто обьявлен, как переменная:

```
let arr2 = new Array();
```

Comment: `b = [...a]`...

Comment: Я так подозреваю что вы ожидаете изменение arr2 снаружи. В таком случае вам стоит изучить основы

Comment: Данный вариант работает не корректно, так как выдает такой результат:

`
Save Deck:[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object]...
`
А должен быть:

`
0: Cards {suits: 'crossbowman', attak: 15, attaktipe: 'ranged', accuracy: 80, health: 100, …}
1: Cards {suits: 'crossbowman', attak: 15, attaktipe: 'ranged', accuracy: 80, health: 100, …}
2: Cards {suits: 'militia', attak: 10, attaktipe: 'melee', accuracy: 80, health: 100, …}
`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Попробуйте создать вместо функции, прототип массива, тогда вы сможете обратиться к `arr2` через `this`

```
Array.prototype.SaveMyDeck = function (target) {
  if (Array.isArray(target) {
    this.push(...target);
  }

  return this;
};
```

Тогда следующий код будет выглядеть так:

```
Array.prototype.SaveMyDeck = function (target) {
  this.push(...target);

  return this;
};

const array = [];

array.SaveMyDeck([1, 2, 3, 4]);

console.log(array); // [1, 2, 3, 4]
```

Comment: Все равно выдает результат:  ` Save Deck:[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object]... ` - это не то, что нужно... Должно получить что-то вроде такого:

` 0: Cards {suits: 'crossbowman', attak: 15, attaktipe: 'ranged', accuracy: 80, health: 100, …} 

1: Cards {suits: 'crossbowman', attak: 15, attaktipe: 'ranged', accuracy: 80, health: 100, …} 

2: Cards {suits: 'militia', attak: 10, attaktipe: 'melee', accuracy: 80, health: 100, …} `

Может поможет уточнение: внутри изначального массива сидят классы...

Comment: @drakoblack, можете скинуть arr1 в нормальном виде, а не в читаемом?

Comment: let MILITIA = new Cards("militia", 10, "melee", 80, 100, 0, 10, 50);
    let DECK_PL = new Array();
    function PushDeck(arr) {
    for (var i = 0; i < 50; i++) {
      arr.push(MILITIA);
    }
}; // заполнение стартовой колоды

Comment: @drakoblack, у вас выводится ` Save Deck:[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object]... `, потому что вы применили сложение типа СТРОКА + МАССИВ (конкатенация), из-за этого у вас все находится в строке, попробуйте написать: console.log('Save Deck:', this)

Comment: Спасибо, совет помог. Я просто написал console.log(arr1); и все заработало... Не думал, что небольшой комментарий в виде текста в консоли может привести к подобным результатам. Буду знать на будущее.

Answer (score 0):

Ты переопределяешь аргумент функции просто, а тебе нужно изменить элементы массива по ссылке к нему.

```
const a = [1, 2, 3, 4];
const result = []
result.push(...a)
```